# Jpanel size automatically changes

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jpanel, grouplayout

I am using a Jpanel an adding JLabels that contains Icons to it. I am using GroupLayout. My problem is that when I try to add the seventh component the Jpanel changes its size by itself although there is still enough space for it to add other components.

The normal working of the Jpanel :

[image]

when I add more elments the JPanel changes the size although there is enough space for new element to be added

[image]

Any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: Did you set the minimum size, the maximum size, the preferred size and the size of your JPanel object?

Comment: `GroupLayout` is a fickle mistress.  Have you tried another layout manager?

Comment: No I didn't. I was hopping that I will find a solution, but if nothing else seems to work I guess I will have to change the layout

Comment: Problem solved by using a left aligned FlowLayout in the Jpanel. Thank you all for your suggestions.